# Set up TextView with method result

Tags: android

I'm a beginner with Java and am stuck in one place. I have a method like this in class 1

```
public String saySomething()
{
    return "blabla";
}
```

Then in Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tw.setText(saySomething());
    }
}
```

I try set return from this method to TextView. Have no idea how but wanted to show what i want to do. How to do it properly?

Comment: It almost looks ok. Do you have a `TextView` in your `activity_main.xml` layout file with an id of `text1`?

Comment: Yes i have TextView in activity_main. I catch Cannot resolve method saySomething()

Comment: That method needs to be in the `MainActivity` class the way you are calling it. Otherwise you need an instance of `Class1` so you can do `class1Instance.saySomething();`

Comment: Can you explaing me what is that exactly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, put saySomething() method in your Activity class or generate an instance of the class hosting the method and call it:

```
ClassName1 className = new ClassName1();
TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
tw.setText(className.saySomething());
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem.Please accept the answer if you found it useful.